# Help needed on ScrollViewer styles

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer

Can any body please provide me, how can we made custom template for the ScrollViewer.

Pointers to any simple tutorials will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
-Narendra

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is get yourself a copy of the existing ScrollViewer template.  Blend makes that very easy.  In VS you have more work to do.  Lets start with a base `UserControl`

```
<UserControl ....>
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer ...>
      <!-- Content here -->
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Got the documentation [ScrollViewer Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278065(v=VS.95).aspx) you'll find the existing xaml for this control here.  Copy it and place it in the `UserControl` resources.

```
<UserControl ....>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
      <!-- copied content of the style from the above link -->
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid ....>
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource MyScrollViewerStyle}">
      <!-- Content here -->
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Now the ScrollViewer looks identical to what you had before.  The difference is you can now start playing around with the `Template` `Setter` in the style to re-arrange and customise the `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 0):

Or build on existing Silverlight themes: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/05/03/new-silverlight-4-themes-available-for-download.aspx